# Could someone please why this program is not running correctly. I'm new to C

Tags: c

Good evening. I just started learning C in college and our 1st assignment was to make a program that calculates the user's bmi. For the life of me I can't figure out why Im not getting the results I want. No matter what height & weight I submit to the program...I keep getting a ridiculously high bmi like 4258544 and then it tells me I'm underweight. i thought I could use another set of eyes.
Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void h_conversion (double *h) {
    *h = *h/12;
}

int bmi_category (double h, double w, double b) {
    b = (w * 4.88)/(h * h);
    if (b < 20)
        return 1;
    else if (b >= 20 && b < 25)
        return 2;
    else if (b >= 25 && b < 30)
        return 3;
    else if (b >= 30 && b < 40)
        return 4;
    else
        return 5;
}

int main (void) {

    double height, weight, bmi;
    double *h, *w, *b;
    h = &height;
    w = &weight;
    b = &bmi;

    printf ("Please enter height (inches): \n");
    scanf (" %lf", &height);

    while ( h <= 0 ) {
        printf ("Weee, this is fun! Try again.\n");
        scanf (" %.2lf", &height);
    }

    if ( *h < 42 || *h > 84 ) 
        printf ("Your entry falls outside the norm for an adult.\n");

    h_conversion( h );

    printf ("Please enter weight (lbs): \n");
    scanf (" %.2lf", &weight);

    while ( w <= 0 ) {
        printf ("This is why we can't have nice things.  Try again.\n");
        scanf (" %.2lf", &weight);
    }

    switch ( bmi_category(*h, *w, *b)) {

    case 1:
        printf ("BMI: %d. Underweight.", (int)&bmi);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf ("BMI: %d. Normal weight.", (int)&bmi);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf ("BMI: %d. Slightly overweight.", (int)&bmi);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf ("BMI: %d. Overweight.", (int)&bmi);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf ("BMI: %d. Extremely overweight.", (int)&bmi);
        break;
    default:
        printf ("error condition\n");
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this article on [how to debug programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It's a valuable skill to learn. See if you can figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 2):

In your printf's you're using

```
(int)&bmi
// this request the address of bmi and casts that value to an integer (addresses are always integers)
```

When you should be using

```
(int)bmi
// this casts the value of the variable bmi to an integer which is what you want.
```

The weird values you're always getting is because you're getting addresses instead of the values of the variables.

Also why all the pointer variables? You only need the h one. The bmi function doesn't require you use pointers so why use them instead of the of its non-pointer counterparts?

Also main returns 0 when it's finished its execution without any issues. For some reason you're returning 1 indicating the program didn't finish execution properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
int bmi_category (double h, double w, double b) {
    b = (w * 4.88)/(h * h);
```

...

```
switch ( bmi_category(*h, *w, *b)) {
case 1:
        printf ("BMI: %d. Underweight.", (int)&bmi);
```

The assignment to `b` inside `bmi_category` will not change the value
of `bmi` in your main routine, as you seem to expect, since you're passing
the value `*b`, rather than the pointer `b`.  And as another answer points out, the `(int)&bmi` expressions are also not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

for double should use it:

```
scanf("%lf", &height);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `bmi_category` function, the parameters were passed incorrectly. You were passing the value when pointer was expected. Because of this, the value of calculated `bmi` was local to the `bmi_category` function and wouldn't get updated to the caller.

When printing the value of `bmi`, you were printing the address `&bmi` instead of the value.

Here is the fixed code with a little cleanup:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void h_conversion(double *h) {
    *h = *h / 12;
}

int bmi_category(const double *h, const double *w, double *b) {
    *b = (*w * 4.88) / (*h * *h);
    if (*b < 20)
        return 1;
    else if (*b >= 20 && *b < 25)
        return 2;
    else if (*b >= 25 && *b < 30)
        return 3;
    else if (*b >= 30 && *b < 40)
        return 4;
    else
        return 5;
}

int main(void) {

    double height, weight, bmi;

    printf("Please enter height (inches): \n");
    scanf(" %lf", &height);

    while (height <= 0) {
        printf("Weee, this is fun! Try again.\n");
        scanf(" %lf", &height);
    }

    if (height < 42 || height > 84)
        printf("Your entry falls outside the norm for an adult.\n");

    h_conversion(&height);

    printf("Please enter weight (lbs): \n");
    scanf(" %lf", &weight);

    while (weight <= 0) {
        printf("This is why we can't have nice things.  Try again.\n");
        scanf(" %lf", &weight);
    }

    switch (bmi_category(&height, &weight, &bmi)) {

    case 1:
        printf("BMI: %d. Underweight.", (int)bmi);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("BMI: %d. Normal weight.", (int)bmi);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("BMI: %d. Slightly overweight.", (int)bmi);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("BMI: %d. Overweight.", (int)bmi);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("BMI: %d. Extremely overweight.", (int)bmi);
        break;
    default:
        printf("error condition\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```